# Rigid body tower falling over by itself?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I have a large tower (12 blocks high) that I plan to have a ball thrown at it. But what happens is that it falls over by itself and starts to spread out on the ground. What is happening and why?
[image]

[Blend File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zq3e4io6hxoi4hj/tower%202.blend?dl=0)

Comment: You need to keyframe the dynamic check box for each piece that you want to move.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that rigid body physics are taking over your tower, and making it collapse before the ball hits it, which is what would happen in real life, if the tower was already broken. The way to fix this is to go under *Properties* > *Physics* > *Rigid Body Dynamics* and check *Enable Deactivation* and *Start Deactivated*.